# Opencart 3x menu edition

Tags: opencart-3

I have a problem with custom menu, I want to add new category to back from store to main website. From template designer /common edit file menu.

```
{% if categories %}
<div class="container">
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">{{ text_category }}</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> **that is my new line for new category** 
        {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.children %}
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }}</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for child in children %}
                <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endfor %}</div>
            <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a> </div>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I have success with add new category, but when try to open link they first take link from sait and then my href ... for example something like this

```
www.storewebsite.com/www.myhreflink.com
```

I don't know from where take this ...

Answer (score 0):

oh.. i found what is wrong .. just need to write link with http://.... and evrything work .

Hope this post will help someone else.. :)

GL